# how to set rest framwork in django settings.py file

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

INSTALLED_APPS = [
*'rest_framwork'*,  **#is this correct#**
'movie.apps.MovieConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please check the link out on how to ask question in stackoverflow. It might help you and the users to better understand the issues/questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have spelling mistake in my case it's not 'rest_framwork' ---- its actually 'rest_framework'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation provided in the link : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Add `rest_framework` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework',
]
```

I think in your case, you are misspelling `rest_framwork`.

Comment: thank you so much you solved my two days of tension thank you Mr.shivendra pratap